# Delete old files using C++

Tags: c++, file-io, dirent.h

I have to delete all files older than n days in a given directory using c++.

FYI, I am using "dirent" for certain file operation like list all files in given directory, but not sure how to check date attributes and apply math to delete files older than n days.

Please advise.

Comment: There is no cross-platform solution.

Comment: you might look at boost filesystem but i doubt it supports both platforms and mod date

Comment: If you're using POSIX anyway ("dirent" is POSIX), have a look at [`fstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat). However, I don't know if this works on mobile platforms like Android and iOS... Once you have a timestamp in seconds, you can simply compare it to the current time and see if it is less than `n * 86400` (a day has 86400 seconds)

Comment: thanks to all of you. Let me see if i can "fstat" as Leems suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult. The language itself provides no support for file system, even in new C++11 standard. (It is a proposal for the next technical report "C++ TR2".)

Boost has no official support for Android and iOS. Qt 4.x neither.

However, Qt 5 will support Android and iOS. It seems to be just released, so maybe you can give it a try. File system support is part of its QtCore module (e.g., `QFile` and `QDir`).